# can I prepend a token (such as 'time') to the launch command for a VSCode debug task?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set up a `launch.json` [configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) such that each time a debug session is launched, it launches with a shell command **prepended** to the actual command?

I may not be using the exact right nouns here, what I basically want is to say:  "every time you run the debugger, instead of just running `program.py [args]` in the terminal/shell, I want you to run `time program.py [args]`.

It's safe to assume that whatever I'm prepending is compatible with the shell/terminal I'm using.  (BASH in this particular case, but it could just as easily be `/usr/bin/time` to get more/better data for each run...).

The [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) don't appear to have this - changing the actual program to include `time` doesn't work because that whole string isn't a valid program.  You can append arguments using the `arg` attribute, but not **prepend** anything that way.

Answer (score 1):

What is the use of timing a program running in a debugger. A debugger slows down the program.

What you could do is create a task that starts the program.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "time current file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "time python ${file}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm aware, but I often use the shortcut to "just run" rather than "run in the debugger".  The distinction between a "configuration" and a "task" was the important piece I was missing here.  Thanks.

Comment: @ljwobker If you designate the task as build task you can use a keyboard shortcut